# [Error] Objects.pas(97): Incompatible types

Tags: ооп, объекты, delphi, delphi-7, база-данных

Есть база данных описатель, котрая содержит структуру базы данных (а именно в отдельных таблицах списко таблиц, список индексов, список ограничений (первичных и внеших ключей), список полей и т. д.). Цель каждому объекту (таблице, индексу, ограничению, домену и т. д.) создать объект. Я сейчас работаю над описанием классов этих объектов:

```
unit Objects;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
type
  TDataTypeID = (DataTypeId_String, DataTypeId_SmallInt, DataTypeId_Integer,
  DataTypeId_Word, DataTypeId_Boolean, DataTypeId_Float, DataTypeId_Currency,
  DataTypeId_BCD, DataTypeId_FMTBCD, DataTypeId_Date, DataTypeId_Time,
  DataTypeId_DateTime, DataTypeId_Timestamp, DataTypeId_Bytes, DataTypeId_Varbytes,
  DataTypeId_Blob, DataTypeId_Memo, DataTypeId_Graphic, DataTypeId_FMTMemo,
  DataTypeId_FixedChar, DataTypeId_WideString, DataTypeId_LargeInt, DataTypeId_Array,
  DataTypeId_FixedWideChar, DataTypeId_WideMemo);
type
  TAlignSpec=(AlignSpec_Left, AlignSpec_Right, AlignSpec_Center);
  TDomainSpec = class(TComponent)
  private
    FName : String;
    FDescription : String;
    FDataTypeId : TDataTypeId;
    FLength : Cardinal;
    FCharLength : Cardinal;
    FPrecision : Cardinal;
    FScale : Cardinal;
    FWidth : Word;
    FAlignSpec : TAlignSpec;
    FShowNull : Boolean;
    FShowLeadNulls : Boolean;
    FThousandsSeparator : Boolean;
  public
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property DataTypeId: TDataTypeId read FDataTypeId;
    property Length: Cardinal read FLength;
    property CharLength: Cardinal read FCharLength;
    property Precision: Cardinal read FPrecision;
    property Scale: Cardinal read FScale;
    property Width: Word read FWidth;
    property Align: TAlignSpec read FAlignSpec;
    property ShowNull: Boolean read FShowNull;
    property ShowLeadNulls: Boolean read FShowLeadNulls;
    property ThousandsSeparator: Boolean read FThousandsSeparator;
  end;
  TFieldSpec=class(TComponent)
  private
    FPosition : integer;
    FName : string;
    FDescription : string;
    FCan_input : Boolean;
    FCan_edit : Boolean;
    FShow_in_grid : Boolean;
    FShow_in_details : Boolean;
    FIs_mean : Boolean;
    FAutocalculated : Boolean;
    FRequired : Boolean;
    FDomainSpec : TComponent;
  public
    function GetTable(): TComponent;
    property Position : integer read FPosition;
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property Can_input : Boolean read FCan_input;
    property Can_edit : Boolean read FCan_edit;
    property Show_in_grid : Boolean read FShow_in_grid;
    property Show_in_details : Boolean read FShow_in_details;
    property Is_mean : Boolean read FIs_mean;
    property Autocalculated : Boolean read FAutocalculated;
    property Required : Boolean read FRequired;
    property TableSpec : TComponent read GetTable;
    property DomainSpec : TComponent read FDomainSpec;
  end;
  TTableSpec=class(TComponent)
  private
    FName : string;
    FDescription : string;
    FCan_add : Boolean;
    FCan_edit : Boolean;
    FCan_delete : Boolean;
    FFields : TComponent;
  public
    function GetField(Name : string):TComponent;
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property Can_add : Boolean read FCan_add;
    property Can_edit : Boolean read FCan_edit;
    property Can_delete : Boolean read FCan_delete;
    property Fields : TComponent read GetField;
  end;
  TIndexSpec=class(TComponent)
  private
    FName : string;
    FUniqueness : Boolean;
    FTable : TComponent;
    FFields : TComponent;
    FExpression : string;
    FDescend : Boolean;
  public
    function GetField(Name : string):TComponent;
    function GetTable():TComponent;
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Uniqueness : Boolean read FUniqueness;
    property Table : TComponent read GetTable;
    property Expression : String read FExpression;
    property Descend : Boolean read FDescend;
    property Fields : TComponent read GetField;
  end;
  TConstraint=class(TComponent)
  private
    FName : String;
    FConstraint_type : String;
    FReference : Integer;
    FTable : TComponent;
    FUnique_key_id : Integer;
    FHas_value_edit : Boolean;
    FCascading_delete : Boolean;
    FExpression : String;
    FField : TComponent;
  public
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Constraint_type : String read FConstraint_type;
    property Reference : Integer read FReference;
    property Table : TComponent read FTable;
    property Unique_key_id : Integer read FUnique_key_id;
    property Has_value_edit : Boolean read FHas_value_edit;
    property Cascading_delete : Boolean read FCascading_delete;
    property Expression : String read FExpression;
    property Field : TComponent read FField;
end;    
  TDBSchemaSpec=class(TComponent)
  private
    FDomains : TComponent;
    FTables : TComponent;
  public
    function GetDomain(Name : string):TComponent;
    function GetTable(Name : string):TComponent;
    property Domains : TComponent read GetDomain;
    property Tables: TComponent read GetTable;
end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function TTableSpec.GetField(Name : string) : TComponent;
begin
   Result:=self.FindComponent(Name);
end;

function TIndexSpec.GetField(Name :string) : TComponent;
begin
   Result:=self.FindComponent(Name);
end;

function TDBSchemaSpec.GetDomain(Name : string) : TComponent;
begin
   Result:=self.FindComponent(Name);
end;

function TDBSchemaSpec.GetTable(Name : string) : TComponent;
begin
   Result:=self.FindComponent(Name);
end;

function TFieldSpec.GetTable():TComponent;
begin
    Result:=Owner;
end;

function TIndexSpec.GetTable():TComponent;
begin
    Result:=Owner;
end;
end.
```

При компиляции я получил следующие ошибки:

```
[Error] Objects.pas(97): Incompatible types
[Error] Objects.pas(115): Incompatible types
[Error] Objects.pas(146): Incompatible types
[Error] Objects.pas(147): Incompatible types
[Hint] Objects.pas(89): Private symbol 'FFields' declared but never used
[Hint] Objects.pas(103): Private symbol 'FTable' declared but never used
[Hint] Objects.pas(141): Private symbol 'FDomains' declared but never used
[Hint] Objects.pas(142): Private symbol 'FTables' declared but never used
[Fatal Error] FirstTask.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Objects.pas'
```

Во-первых, непонятно почему возникает ошибка `Incompatible types`. Во-вторых, как мне было сказано, если есть к примеру поле `FFields : TComponent` и при создании объекта `TTableSpec` будет создан объект `TFieldSpec`, то он станет присутствовать в массиве `Components` соответсвующего экземпляра `TTableSpec` и его можно будет найти по имени с помощью метода `FindComponent(Name)`. Возникает вопрос: правильно ли я использовал слово `self` в методах `TTableSpec.GetField, TIndexSpec.GetField, TDBSchemaSpec.GetDomain, TDBSchemaSpec.GetTable`. В-третьих, хочу спросить может для соответствующих свойств (например, `Fields` в `TTableSpec`) может лучше использовать тип `TFieldSpec`, но тогда возникает вопрос возможно ли приведение типа `TComponent` к `TFieldSpec` в методе `TTableSpec.GetField`?

Answer (score 2):

**Incompatible types** не совместимые типы, пробуйте хоть переводить ошибки.

Comment: @savro я знаю перевод, я спрашиваю откуда она возникает (и не только про это)?

Comment: @savro вернее почему (а не откуда) она возникает?

Answer (score 1):

**Во-первых**, GetField и проч у вас идут с параметрами, коих у данного геттера быть не должно. Т.е. должно быть `function GetField:TComponent;`
**Во-вторых**, неверное утверждение. Само ничего не создается. У TComponent есть возможность только удалять принадлежащие ему компоненты (те, у которых Owner является этим компонентом). Ваш код нерабочий и то, что вы использовали тоже.
**В третьих**, с этого надо было начинать. Построить иерархию классов. От TComponent наследован в лучшем случае должен быть только один класс. В качестве наследников в качестве обучения могут быть как TObject (т.е. весь необходимый функционал будете строить сами, чтоб потом не ссылаться на "как мне было сказано", а точно знать что и как будет создано, удалено и т.д.), так и например TCollection, TOwnedCollection и TCollectionItem где некоторые методы уже реализованы.

Забудьте про TComponent. От TComponent будете наследоваться только если вам вдруг захочется (теоретически) данный класс добавить на панель компонентов рядом с другими - TLabel, TPanel... Скажем, TTable может быть компонентом, а tfield, tconstraint врядли...

Вот вам для начала рыба для TFields, создайте дальше TField, TTable и прочие необходимые вам классы, постройте из них иерархию. В качестве подсказке используйте исходники vcl (DB.pas, Classes.pas и т.д.).

```
TFields = class
  FFields: TList;
private
  function GetField(I: Integer): TField;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy;override;
  property Field[I: Integer]: TField read GetField;default;
end;

constructor TFields.Create;
begin
  FFields:=TList.Create;
end;

destructor TFields.Destroy;
begin
  for i:=FFields.Count-1 downto 0 do
    TField(FFields[i]).Free;
  FFields.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TFields.GetField(I: Integer): TField;
begin
  Result:=TField(FFields[i]);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
property Fields : TComponent read GetField;
```

Надо наверное что то типа

```
property Fields[name:string] : TComponent read GetField;
```

Вы же индексное свойство создаёте.

Ну думаю далее проблемы в том же ключе...